# Get sum of column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is

```
SELECT 
    AIP.TERMID,
    (SELECT COUNT(RAU.TERMNAME) 
     FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU 
     WHERE RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4) AS page_views
FROM REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
GROUP BY AIP.TERMID
```

I need to get the total of column `page_views`. How can I get it? Please help. PHP and ORACLE.

[image]

I need total of `page_views` as 2 (1+1). I need to get it as new row without changing the existing query.

```
SELECT 
    AIP.TERMID,
    (SELECT COUNT(RAU.TERMNAME) 
     FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU 
     WHERE RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4) AS page_views,
    (SELECT SUM(COUNT(RAU.TERMNAME)) 
     FROM REPORT_API_USAGE RAU 
     WHERE RAU.VOCID = 4 GROUP BY AIP.TERMID) AS page_views
FROM REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
GROUP BY AIP.TERMID`
```

I tried this but giving a result `4` instead of `2`

[image]

Comment: Please add some data.

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: in your example is **NO** `SUM` there is a count is this a typo?

Comment: The `SUM` ? You are using a `COUNT` in your query

Comment: I am getting individual count. I need to get overall sum of all individual count.

Comment: @drup post data as asked in comments to get result you want

Comment: Of course you will get 1 as page_views as you added the count() in it and you are grouping it by Term_id which are different for each one.

Comment: Try with Group by Term_id and Term_name.

Comment: You will need a `SUM() OVER ()` on your  query. I added an example to my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to show ? The total of page views per TERMID ?

```
SELECT aip.TERMID,
  COUNT(rau.TERMNAME) AS PAGE_VIEWS
FROM REPORT_API_PAGES aip
  JOIN REPORT_API_USAGE rau ON rau.TERMID = aip.TERMID
WHERE rau.VOCID = 4
GROUP BY aip.TERMID
```

Although, with your current query, the join is not even needed (unless you have rows in `REPORT_API_USAGE` with no parent in `REPORT_API_PAGES`)

```
SELECT rau.TERMID,
  COUNT(rau.TERMNAME) AS PAGE_VIEWS
FROM REPORT_API_USAGE rau
WHERE rau.VOCID = 4
GROUP BY rau.TERMID
```

EDIT: So, based on the update of your question, if you only want the total of pageviews, you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(rau.TERMNAME) AS page_views
FROM REPORT_API_PAGES aip
  JOIN REPORT_API_USAGE rau ON rau.TERMID = aip.TERMID
WHERE rau.VOCID = 4
```

(The join is not necessary, it allows you to only count the page views for pages where the `TERMID` is defined in the `REPORT_API_PAGES` table)

EDIT2: Based on your second update, I suggest you to use `SUM(PAGE_VIEWS) OVER ()` on your subquery

```
SELECT TERMID,
  PAGE_VIEWS,
SUM(PAGE_VIEWS) OVER () AS TOTAL_PAGE_VIEWS
FROM (
  SELECT aip.TERMID,
    COUNT(rau.TERMNAME) AS PAGE_VIEWS
  FROM REPORT_API_PAGES aip
    LEFT OUTER JOIN REPORT_API_USAGE rau ON (rau.TERMID = aip.TERMID AND rau.VOCID = 4)
  GROUP BY aip.TERMID)
```

Obviously you can replace the subquery with your original query as well.

Comment: with his join he can and surely will get a other result if `aip` and `rau` doesn't contain the same `TERMID`

Comment: He might get more rows, but the number of page views per TERMID will always be the same (this is what I specified between parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AIP.TERMID,
(
  select count(RAU.TERMNAME) 
  FROM 
      REPORT_API_USAGE RAU 
  WHERE
      RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4
) as page_views
from 
  REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
GROUP BY 
  AIP.TERMID
```

just try modifying this to like this

```
select sum(page_views)
(
  SELECT AIP.TERMID,
  (
   select count(RAU.TERMNAME) 
   FROM 
      REPORT_API_USAGE RAU 
   WHERE
      RAU.TERMID = AIP.TERMID AND RAU.VOCID = 4
  ) as page_views
  from 
    REPORT_API_PAGES AIP
  GROUP BY 
    AIP.TERMID
) from dual;
```